# Use return in constructor for wrapping node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm playing with Node and ES6 and I'm trying to wrap some Node modules into classes (in this case bunyan). The goal is to unify the way I use modules (both mine and npm ones) in my app (not sure it's a good thing).

I came up with a working solution involving a return in the class constructor. But I'm not sure it's a good way to do it. Any thoughts ?

Here's what I'm doing :

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');

export default class Logger {

  constructor(options) {
    return bunyan.createLogger(options);
  }
};
```

So i can use it like this :

```
var logger  = new Logger({name: "server.js"});
```

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a matter of opinion, but there are a couple of (mostly) objective points to be made:

If you do this...

- An object is created by the `new` operator and then just thrown away (provided the V8 optimizer doesn't figure out it can skip that).
- It's fairly misleading that the `logger` you get back is *not* an instance of the `Logger` class (`logger instanceof Logger` will be false). The ability to return an object from a constructor to override the one that `new` creates is largely for returning a previous instance created by the constructor that's equivalent to the one you asked for (largely for singletons or immutable objects, to avoid duplication).
- Using `new Logger` hides the fact that what you get back is actually a bunyan logger, which can throw off people maintaining the code.

Whether you consider those "cons" or not is, again, a matter of opinion.

An alternative would be for `Logger` to *use* a bunyan logger rather than directly returning it. This would also have the advantage of encapsulating it if you decided to swap bunyan out for something else in the future.

Comment: Ok. I'll see about wrapping Bunyan by having my object calling its methods. Thanks !